# Retrieve live tweets from Twitter API

Tags: node.js, twitter, sttwitterapi

I am trying to pull LIVE tweets from selected user from Twitter users.
‘statuses/user_timeline.json’ API endpoint retrieving all the tweets of user but I wan't to filter only tweets which are currently LIVE.

So is there any way to retrieve only LIVE tweets of specific twitter user?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. First, get the most recent tweet from this user using `statuses/user_timeline`, and save the tweet's `id`. Then, on some interval that does not exceed the rate limit, request `statuses/user_timeine` again but with the `since_id` parameter set to the `id` that you saved.

Here is Twitter's doc: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html